# If I ping 192.168.1.4, why is 192.168.1.2 responding?

Tags: ping

When I run the command `ping 192.168.1.4` I get the following results:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.4 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
```

Can anyone help me understand why in the world it's telling me that 192.168.1.2 is unreachable when that's not the IP address I typed in?  I'm very confused.

Also in case it's relevant, I'm on a workgroup.

Comment: What command have you typed *exactly*?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in quotes.

Comment: BVernon: it doesn't say "192.168.1.2" is unreachable. On the contrary, it is 192.168.1.2 that say that the Destination host (ie, 192.168.1.4) is unreachable. In your case .1.2 is probably your own machine. But it could also be a "hop" along the way to the destination (the last hop that was reached). It could mean that the destination is not answering ping (due to its firewall, for example. do NOT disable the firewall! just allow incoming ICMP)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`192.168.1.2` should be your ip, not the destination host. If the destination host is unreachable, it can not send you a reply (obviously), so the reply comes from your own machine.

This is because on the same subnet, `ping` sends an ARP request to get the MAC-Adress corresponding to the IP. if this cant be resolved, you get this message. If you ping a machine on another subnet, you get a time out message, because `ping` sends an ARP request to get the Gateway of the subnet, which should complete fine. But then the actual pinging times out

Comment: You can confirm it's your ip by typing `ipconfig /all`

Comment: Ah, I feel like a dummy for not noticing that.  The original problem (that it was pinging the wrong ip address for a specific computer name) has fixed itself over night.  However, I still find it odd that I can't get on my router (192.168.1.1) from this machine even though it doesn't seem to be setup any different than other machines on my network.  But at this point that's not slowing me down so I'll save that conundrum for another day.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.1.2 is some computer along the way, directly connected with your pc, telling you it cannot complete its task.

For instance, supposed your pc is cable-linked to another pc, which should be connected via wifi to a network, but the wifi connection dropped for any reason. Then the pc you are connect to do will send exactly the reply you have received.

Like Hercules' pillars, it is saying, *nec plus ultra*, i.e. no further than here. It means 192.168.1.2 has a connectivity problem.

Comment: The last sentence is true, but the first sentence misses the most simple possibility: that 192.168.1.2, the computer with connectivity problems, is the PC itself.

Comment: Nope: when the pc issuing the ping command is the one without connection, there is no "Reply from ..." statement.

Comment: FYI, 192.168.1.2 is the computer where the ping was originating but no it did not have a connectivity problem as I was obviously having no trouble getting on the internet and posting this question from it.

Comment: +1 anyway though cause maybe that info will help someone with a similar but different problem down the road.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae i explained in my answer why there is a reply in this case