# If I ping when disconnected, why is 192.168.1.2 responding?

Tags: networking, ping

When searching, found [if-i-ping-192-168-1-4-why-is-192-168-1-2-responding](https://superuser.com/questions/669738/if-i-ping-192-168-1-4-why-is-192-168-1-2-responding), but my case is different.

On Windows 7 laptop where `ipconfig /all` gives all disconnected (3 wireless, 1 ethernet and 1 tunnel - I don't know why so many: Lenovo laptop with Lenovo drivers, wifi off, no cable at that moment) pining something gives `Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.` Pining 192.168.1.2 gives proper reply.

The question arose actually when I was trying to establish direct Ethernet connection to other laptop. I got IP automatically from that laptop with prefix `169`, but error when pining was from `192`, which surprised me (wi-fi was off, only Ethernet was on). `192` is prefix my home router gives, maybe glitch from saved history of previous wifi connection? How to make it use Ethernet and new prefix now?

P.S. address actually 1.3 in my case, wrote 1.2 to make it like existing question, maybe it matters...

Comment: I dont do Windows, so it's just an educated guess. 192.168.1.2 was an IP address associated with that machine, and it was still in the ARP table.

Comment: I can't quite follow what you're asking but i'd note that sometimes pings can be blocked like ping responses not given, so it's not a conclusive test of if a host is there, and if you get destination host unreachable then maybe the host is not responding to  pings.  As for a 169 address, i've seen that on a laptop that can't connect to the internet and there's an error, I don't know if they have LAN connection i've assumed not, i've never tried pinging such an address., it's interesting that you claim you got a response from it

Comment: @barlop, thank you! Looking more into it I see I used Local-Link address (169) for connection between laptops, so maybe it cannot be used if I want to allow traffic to go to internet via it.

Comment: "Destination host unreachable" comes from whichever node was unable to route the ICMP packet to the next level. Likely, that is the IP of your own computer or a gateway it is connected to.

Comment: Your description of the problem is very difficult to understand.  Can you take some time and rewrite it to be more clear.